# Ways to change the elemental type of a spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric

In Pathfinder, Wizards can take the [Admixture](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/evocation/admixture) school, which lets them switch elemental damage types. Some Sorcerer bloodlines (e.g. Elemental Acid bloodline) let you convert into a particular type.

What other options are there? In particular, are there any options available to either a Cleric or an Oracle? (Feats, traits, items, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of only five ways to change the elemental subtype of a spell dealing energy damage :

1. [Elemental Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/elemental-spell-metamagic) Metamagic Feat
2. Wizard's [Admixture](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/evocation/admixture) school
3. Five Sorcerer [bloodlines](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines) (Elemental, plus one for every elemental Genie : Shaitan, Efreeti, Djinni, Marid)
4. The [Metamagic Rod](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/metamagic-rods/metamagic-elemental)
5. The 10th level [Bloodmage prestige class](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/a-b/bloatmage)

Comment: this is off-topic since you asked spefically for damage spells, but casting [Summon Monster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster) to summon an elemental change the subtype of the spell.

Comment: There are some sublte differences here. The Meamagic Feat and Rod don't change the descriptor, and don't require the initial damage to have been one of the elemental type.

Answer (score 5):

There's this feat ;

> **Elemental Spell (Metamagic)**
>
> You can manipulate the elemental nature of
> your spells.
>
> **Benefit:** Choose one energy type: acid, cold, electricity, or fire. You
> may replace a spell’s normal damage with that energy type or split the
> spell’s damage, so that half is of that energy type and half is of its
> normal type.
>
> **Level Increase:** +1 (an elemental spell uses up a spell slot one level
> higher than the spell’s actual level.)
>
> **Special:** You can gain this feat multiple times. Each time you must
> choose a different energy type.

Comment: Note that in 3.5, the same feat also could choose the superior Sonic damage type, left the spell the same spell level, and was *still* a fairly weak feat. You may wish to talk to your DM about this; having an elemental theme should not mean getting spells a spell level late.

Comment: It also seems rather inferior to the psion's energy powers (Energy Ray, Energy Burst, Energy Ball, Energy Bolt, etc.), which allows the psion to choose PER MANIFESTATION which energy type to use (fire, electricity, cold, or sonic [but no acid]) at no additional power point cost.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add, expanding on KRyan's comment to Can Canbek's answer, that these various rules are used to let a spellcaster change a spell's energy damage type *some of the time*. A djinn-blooded sorcerer, for instance, can cast a *fireball* normally one time, or change it to an *electricity ball* another.

However, if you want a cold-themed character, for instance, just talk to your GM about taking standard fire- or electricity-based spells and reskinning them as cold based spells. This wouldn't require a feat or character option since you're not being given the versatility and flexibility of changing a spell's energy, just inventing a new spell - *chill wave*, for instance, that happens to be identical to the relevant fire spell (say, *burning hands*) but for frost.